# Textblock digit animation windows phone

Tags: windows, xaml, animation, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have a TextBlock in my Windows Phone app which contains numbers. What i wanna do is animating the digits of those numbers when i change the text of the textblock. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you